# Video upload from iPhone device fails but works on Simulator perfectly ERROR:'Cannot read file'

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, aws-sdk-ios

I am trying to upload a video from iPhone device as:

```
var uploadTask = self.session?.uploadTaskWithRequest(request, fromFile:NSURL(string: assetFilePath.path)!)
```

This code works on simulator and gives a session task object which I can resume. But it does not work on iPhone device.

It fails as:

```
2015-05-19 18:36:44.718 myApp[327:24703] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot read file at file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0144.mp4'
```

I tried to check if the video file has read access, but it returns false on iPhone:

```
fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(asset.path)  // returns false
```

Anybody has encountered this before, or am I doing something wrong here?

Code which I am using to get the file path is :

```
    let options = PHFetchOptions()
    options.sortDescriptors = [
        NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true)
    ]
    currentVideofetch = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(.Video, options: options)
    let asset = self.currentVideofetch.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? PHAsset  
    var assetLength:NSNumber!
    var assetFilePath:NSString!

    if let checkdAsset = asset {
        PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageDataForAsset(checkdAsset,options: nil) {
            imageData,dataUTI,orientation,info in

            assetLength = imageData.length as NSNumber
            let assetFilePathUrl  = info["PHImageFileURLKey"] as? NSURL
            assetFilePath = assetFilePathUrl!.absoluteString! 
            println("Assets FilePath \(assetFilePath)") // returns file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0144.mp4
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to use requestAVAssetForVideo instead requestImageDataForAsset?

Answer (score 1):

After messing up with lot. This is classic permissions issue in iOS. Unfortunately I didn't get any straight answers to this. We had to copy file to our local directory of my App. After that everything is works like a charm.
But in case of large file I send copying file logic in background task.